# Handling smileys in android

Tags: android, textview, emoji, android-keypad

Recently completed an application and have been informed that when users add smileys to their comments, they show up the first time and the disappear.

I have displayed the comments using `comment.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`

I had never really considered smileys and this is my first time of trying to handle them with an app. What is the default behaviour with with displaying smileys in a textview. I have checked on my default keypad and there are no smileys so users might be using a custom keypad. What is the best way to stop handle input from custom keypads or handle smileys generally within an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Span allow you to format code as you want. You can use an [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) to render the input text ":-)" by any bitmap in a TextView :

```
String text = "here is a smiley :-)";
String smileyStr = ":-)";
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Here's a smiley :-)");
int smileyStart = text.indexOf(smileyStr);
Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.emoticon);
ss.setSpan(new ImageSpan(smiley), text.indexOf(smileyStr), smileyStr.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 
textView.setText(ss);
```

You can find out more here :
http://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/

Comment: What if a smiley is selected directly from a keypad? Does this handle that as well?